# How can I get the default create-react-app to work on older iPhones?

Tags: ios, create-react-app, iphone-6

I am testing the default create-react-app on older iPhones using browserstack.com. The default create-react-app works on iPhone 7, but not iPhone 6.

Some of my users have these older iPhones and my own app that I created with create-react-app is not working on them. I am deploying it by 'npm run build' and then ftp to my server with FileZilla. So no Netlify, etc.

Anyone know how to fix this?